# Problem switching from tetex to texlive

Tags: texmaker

I use Slackware 14.1 which, as you may know, comes with tetex. I have just recently begun exploring tex using texmaker and tetex. However I quickly discovered that tetex is way out of date and decided to switch to texlive. I downloaded and installed texlive and removed tetex. The problem is that now, when I use texmaker it is looking for the old .sty files from the tetex installation which are no longer there! How would I go about telling texmaker to look in the new texlive folders?

Comment: Not sure about the .sty files, but [Configuring the latex related commands](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/doc.html#SECTION02) in the Texmaker user manual shows where you can force the path to the TeX binaries. I'd assume using those would also use the TeX Live support files. Alternatively, maybe you haven't totally uninstalled tetex, and it's still using them by default? What does `which tex` return at a command line: something in /usr/local, or something in just /usr ?

Comment: It looks like my texmaker isn't paying any attention the the PATH variable for some reason. I installed texstudio and had the same thing happen however I decided to force texstudio (which I like better, having used it over the weekend) to find the proper binaries. Works fine now!! Strange problem. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it's work on slackware and Texmaker, but I'm using TexStudio (which is a fork of texmaker) and linux Mint, as I've replaced the stock installation of TexLive with teh last distribution of TeXLive downloaded from the site.

I have to install TeXlive in my home directory and put this in my `.profile` file

```
PATH=$HOME/bin/texlive/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH; export PATH 
MANPATH=$HOME/bin/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/man:$MANPATH; export MANPATH 
INFOPATH=$HOME/bin/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/info:$INFOPATH; export INFOPATH
```

All is working flawlessy with the new TexLive.

obviuously you have to tune this for you installation pointing to the paths where you have installed the new TeXLive distribution.

you can test where your Tex installation search for the files with this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "which kpsexpand: `which kpsexpand`"
echo "TEXMFDIST:       `kpsexpand '$TEXMFDIST'`"
echo "TEXMFLOCAL:      `kpsexpand '$TEXMFLOCAL'`"
echo "TEXMFHOME:       `kpsexpand '$TEXMFHOME'`"
echo "TEXMFCONFIG:     `kpsexpand '$TEXMFCONFIG'`"
echo "TEXMFSYSCONFIG:  `kpsexpand '$TEXMFSYSCONFIG'`"
echo "TEXMFVAR:        `kpsexpand '$TEXMFVAR'`"
echo "TEXMFSYSVAR:     `kpsexpand '$TEXMFSYSVAR'`"
echo "TEXMFCACHE:      `kpsexpand '$TEXMFCACHE'`"
```

maybe this will help you to point out where the problem is and adjust some paths to make all work.

Check if `printenv` tell you that some TEX variable are referring to the old tetex installation and if so find were these variables are set maybe in /etc/bashrc or /etc/profile but I don't know Slackware enough to help you further.

Also you have to control what `kpsexpand` you are calling maybe it is the old one and it set the path incorrectly